# How to access DataGridView properties on an already designed Windows Form

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview, vsto, office-addins

I had already designed a windows form (**Form1**) with a DataGridView on it, I also have a ribbon with a button on it in which I want when I click on it, it run a code like bellow:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As RibbonControlEventArgs) Handles 
Button2.Click
    Dim f As Form1
    f = New Form1
    f.Show()
'(Room for my question)
end sub
```

I want to be able to access my datagridview user control to add columns and rows programmatically.

How should I do that?

Comment: The form containing the grid should be the only place the grid gets manipulated. The other form should pass whatever data is required for the grid form to do that, by setting one or more properties or pass arguments to a method, which includes the form constructor. If you really must do it the bad way though, the field you use to access the control within the form is `Public` by default, so you can use it to access the grid outside the form too. If you do it that way, just make sure you do it BEFORE you call `Show`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a Public Sub on form one which where you will put the changes that you want make on the the Datagridview then call it on the Button2_Click event of your Form2.

Example:
Form 1:

```
Public Sub AddToDGV()
    With DataGridView1
        .Rows.Add(Form2.TextBox1.Text, Form2.TextBox2.Text, Form2.TextBox3.Text)
    End With
End Sub
```

Form2:

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Call Form1.AddToDGV()
End Sub
```